# LocalBroadcastManager not found in androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0 but available in 1.0.0

Tags: android, androidx, localbroadcastmanager

I just migrated to androidx via the option `Refactor -> Move to Androidx` option in Android Studio.
By default the `build.gradle` file was using:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

I am using LocalBroadcastManager in many places in the project. I could perfectly use `import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager` with the above v1.0.0 of the `androidx.appcompat`. But when I update it to 1.1.0 as:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

The import is not working. I am getting `Unresolved reference : localbroadcastmanager` error.

I have tried to clean project and also rebuild project multiple times and the issue still exists.

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AppCompat 1.0.0 had a transitive dependency on `legacy-support-core-utils` (which includes `localbroadcastmanager` so as to maintain exact compatibility with the last Support Library 28.0.0 release.

AppCompat 1.1.0 removed that transitive dependency and now only depends on the exact libraries it needs.

Therefore if your application code still needs `LocalBroadcastManager`, you need to manually add the dependency on LocalBroadcastManager:

```
implementation "androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0"
```

Note that as per the [LocalBroadcastManager 1.1.0-alpha01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/localbroadcastmanager#1.1.0-alpha01):

> `androidx.localbroadcastmanager` is being deprecated in version `1.1.0-alpha01`.
>
> **Reason**
>
> - `LocalBroadcastManager` is an application-wide event bus and embraces layer violations in your app; any component may listen to events from any other component.
> - It inherits unnecessary use-case limitations of system `BroadcastManager`; developers have to use `Intent` even though objects live in only one process and never leave it. For this same reason, it doesn’t follow feature-wise `BroadcastManager`.
>
> These add up to a confusing developer experience.
>
> **Replacement**
>
> You can replace usage of `LocalBroadcastManager` with other implementations of the observable pattern. Depending on your use case, suitable options may be `LiveData` or reactive streams.

Comment: I see. But my app heavily uses LocalBroadcastManager. It won't be possible to switch to something else right now.

Comment: There's no requirement to switch to anything else - being an unbundled library, the 1.0.0 release will continue to function as it always has. Just something to consider when building out new features that perhaps there are way better ways of doing things than `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: I added this  "implementation "androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0" but getting another error "method does not exist on module hmrclient callfunctionreturnflushedqueue". can you help me please. 
thanks