# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.vrtour, PID: 14793

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to integrate navigation on a site map using mapbox but my app crashed when I click on the site map page

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vrtour, PID: 14793
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryService.registerLocationReceiver(TelemetryService.java:163)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryService.createLocationReceiver(TelemetryService.java:158)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryService.onCreate(TelemetryService.java:41)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.vrtour-7_IWX5sSQKzHKJREz6hETw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.vrtour-7_IWX5sSQKzHKJREz6hETw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.vrtour-7_IWX5sSQKzHKJREz6hETw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryService.registerLocationReceiver(TelemetryService.java:163) 
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryService.createLocationReceiver(TelemetryService.java:158) 
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryService.onCreate(TelemetryService.java:41) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

My main activity code

```
    package com.example.vrtour;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.RenderMode;

import java.util.List;

public class SiteMap extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap map;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;
    private Location originLocation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this,getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_site_map);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map= mapboxMap;
        enableLocation();

    }

    private void enableLocation(){
       if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)){
           initializeLocationEngine();
           initializeLocationLayer();
       }else {
           permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
           permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
       }
    }

    private void initializeLocationEngine(){
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();

        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation !=null){
            originLocation = lastLocation;
            setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
        }else{
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationLayer(){
        locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView,map,locationEngine);
        locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
        locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        locationLayerPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);

    }

    private void setCameraPosition(Location location){
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude()), 13.0 ));
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();


    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null){
            originLocation=location;
            setCameraPosition(location);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
    //present toast or dialog
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted){
            enableLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (locationEngine !=null){
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationLayerPlugin !=null){
            locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
        }
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (locationEngine != null){
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null){
            locationLayerPlugin.onStop();
        }
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if ( locationEngine != null){
            locationEngine.deactivate();
        }
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }



}
```

My xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SiteMap">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat= "3.0246"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="101.5161"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12">

    </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'd look here on using androidx libraries: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/ - the part about setting gradle flags.  If you haven't done so - you may need to migrate app to androidx (there's a menu pulldown to automatically perform the upgrade).

Comment: @Andy hi can u explain more, sorry im new to this

is this one 
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

it's already in my gradle.properties

Comment: Consider this answer as it may be as simple as adding a dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58663263/2711811.  It looks like mapbox has a dependency on a library which is not part of your build - the answer identifies the package name to add.

Comment: @Andy okay, I tried adding the dependency, it worked and did not crash, but now it is detecting the wrong location, any idea where to look for this error?